# Selecting records from last 24 hours - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run this MySQL command to select records with a `lead_submitted` date in the last 24 hours.

The issue is it grabs future dates too (***fyi** I'm delaying some leads so basically set a date in the future for these to be processed*).

For example, if I run the command:

`SELECT id, lead_submitted, processed FROM leads WHERE (lead_submitted > now() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR) ORDER BY id DESC;`

I get this result:

`10 | 2022-10-04 13:24:13 | N`

~

Why is this? I just want to select records from the last 24h.

FTR, when I run `SELECT NOW() as now;` I get `2022-09-30 14:00:12`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

**EDIT:**
I've found this works as a workaround, but it feels nasty:

`SELECT id, lead_submitted, processed FROM leads WHERE (lead_submitted > now() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR) AND (lead_submitted < now() + INTERVAL 1 SECOND) AND processed = 'N' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;`

Comment: Your solution is no workaround. It's the way SQL filters rows by timestamp values when you want values in the past 24 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use:

```
SELECT id, lead_submitted, processed 
FROM leads 
WHERE lead_submitted between (now() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR) and now() 
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Comment: Amazing - that does indeed work! Thanks so much for taking the time and replying. I added a wee edit just before your answer came in with a solution but yours is far, far neater :-)